# How to redo filtering with LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

In Microsoft Excel, I can reapply a filter with these commands:

[image: first hit in search engine]

I put this command via shortcut in the top bar and can redo the filtering with just one click:

[image: visualization of Excel shortcut in top bar]

How could I do the same with LibreOffice Calc?

It would be OK to have this option somewhere as an icon in the toolbars.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you mean this Excel command
[image: Reapplay Filter]

In Calc, the AutoFilter is organized somewhat differently - the same action is performed by the [**Data - Refresh Range**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/12100000.html) command.

In the [**Tools - Customize - Toolbars tab**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/06140400.html) menu you can assign a toolbar button to this command.

In the menu [**Tools - Customize - Keyboard tab**](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/01/06140200.html) you can assign the same keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+Alt+L** to this command.

Just like in Excel, this command will be executed if the active cell is in the filtered data range at the time the button or hotkey is pressed.

Слава Україні!

Comment: Слава Україні! :-)